# What is the difference between inheriting from Abstract class vs Inheriting from a similar Concrete class in terms of memory consumption in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, memory, memory-management

I have two classes as such:

```
public abstract class A
{
  public int TheInt {get;set;}
  public string GetString(double dbl)
   {
       return dbl.ToString();
   }
}

public class B
{
  public int TheInt {get;set;}
  public string GetString(double dbl)
   {
       return dbl.ToString();
   }
}
```

And I have two other classes each deriving from either A or B as such:

```
public class C : A
{
}

public class D : B
{
}
```

And I have two objects as this:

```
C objC = new C();
D objD = new D();
```

Will there be any difference in terms of memory consumption between objC and objD? Please explain.

Comment: It's not meant to be offensive, but you should really read more about what [`abstract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members) really means. It has nothing to do with memory consumption(no, an interface doesn't need 0 bytes).

Comment: Memory size equals the sum of the fields in the object plus the size of the inherited fields.  The *abstract* keyword plays no role whatsoever, it affects methods.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, Thank you, I did google and read about it and I arrived at the conclusion that there is no difference in memory consumption (I even did a benchmark and calculated the memory usage in the Garbage Collection). However, I was thinking that there could have been something that I might have missed, so I decided to reach out to the community for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

> Will there be any difference in terms of memory consumption between
>   objC and objD?

No. All that counts is the actual *instantiated* class (that is when calling `new ...`). Only when you *create* an instance of a class, memory gets allocated. The amount of memory therefor is equal to the actual class that is instantiated. The type of the *reference* that points to that instance is completely irrelevant for your memory-consumption. Having said this as your two *instantiated* classes `C` and `D` have the same members, they also have the same memory-footprint.

On the pther hand if you´re up to instantiate an instance of your base-class `B` that is *not abstract*, you *may* have some difference, because it may have less members than your derived class `D` (e.g. `D`also contains a member `FurtherProperty` which is not part of `B`).

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class is a class with some exceptions , Both can have constructors and methods, The run-time will not create separate instance of base classes and child class. So there is nothing to distinguish in terms of memory consumption between two.

Answer (score 0):

The followings are simplified IL code of inheritances of abstract and usual classes:

**Not abstract:**

**C#**

```
public class NotAbstract
{
    public void PrintOut()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(NotAbstract));
    }
}

class Program : NotAbstract
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.PrintOut();
    }
}
```

**IL**

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Abstract_Test_Abstract.NotAbstract
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .method public hidebysig instance void 
          PrintOut() cil managed
  {
//000012:         {
    IL_0000:  nop
//000013:             Console.WriteLine(nameof(NotAbstract));
    IL_0001:  ldstr      "NotAbstract"
    IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000b:  nop
//000014:         }
    IL_000c:  ret
  } // end of method NotAbstract::PrintOut

  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
  } // end of method NotAbstract::.ctor

} // end of class Abstract_Test_Abstract.NotAbstract

.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Abstract_Test_Abstract.Program
       extends Abstract_Test_Abstract.NotAbstract
{
  .method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
  {
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack  1
    .locals init ([0] class Abstract_Test_Abstract.Program p)
//000012:         {
    IL_0000:  nop
//000013:             var p = new Program();
    IL_0001:  newobj     instance void Abstract_Test_Abstract.Program::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  stloc.0
//000014:             p.PrintOut();
    IL_0007:  ldloc.0
    IL_0008:  callvirt   instance void Abstract_Test_Abstract.NotAbstract::PrintOut()
    IL_000d:  nop
//000015:         }
    IL_000e:  ret
  } // end of method Program::Main

  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
  } // end of method Program::.ctor

} // end of class Abstract_Test_Abstract.Program
```

**Abstract:**

**C#**

```
public abstract class IsAbstract
{
    public abstract void PrintOut();
}

class Program : IsAbstract
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.PrintOut();
    }

    public override void PrintOut()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(IsAbstract));
    }
}
```

**IL**

```
.class public abstract auto ansi beforefieldinit Abstract_Test_NotAbstract.IsAbstract
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .method public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual 
          instance void  PrintOut() cil managed
  {
  } // end of method IsAbstract::PrintOut

  .method family hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
  } // end of method IsAbstract::.ctor

} // end of class Abstract_Test_NotAbstract.IsAbstract

.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Abstract_Test_NotAbstract.Program
       extends Abstract_Test_NotAbstract.IsAbstract
{
  .method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
  {
//000012:         {
    IL_0000:  nop
//000013:             var p = new Program();
    IL_0001:  newobj     instance void Abstract_Test_NotAbstract.Program::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  stloc.0
//000014:             p.PrintOut();
    IL_0007:  ldloc.0
    IL_0008:  callvirt   instance void Abstract_Test_NotAbstract.IsAbstract::PrintOut()
    IL_000d:  nop
//000015:         }
    IL_000e:  ret
  } // end of method Program::Main

  .method public hidebysig virtual instance void 
          PrintOut() cil managed
  {
    .maxstack  8
//000016: 
//000017:         public override void PrintOut()
//000018:         {
    IL_0000:  nop
//000019:             Console.WriteLine(nameof(IsAbstract));
    IL_0001:  ldstr      "IsAbstract"
    IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000b:  nop
//000020:         }
    IL_000c:  ret
  } // end of method Program::PrintOut

  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
  } // end of method Program::.ctor

} // end of class Abstract_Test_NotAbstract.Program
```

As you can see there is no any evidence of any extra memory consumption.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I have run a benchmark as follows on the problem and arrived at the conclusion that the **memory consumption is the same in both objC and objD**.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkC(); //Gives 24
        //BenchmarkD(); //Gives 24
    }

    static void BenchmarkC()
    {
        long StopBytes = 0;
        long StartBytes = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        C objC = new C();
        StopBytes = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        GC.KeepAlive(objC);
        Console.WriteLine(StopBytes - StartBytes);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void BenchmarkD()
    {
        long StopBytes = 0;
        long StartBytes = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        D objD = new D();
        StopBytes = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        GC.KeepAlive(objD);
        Console.WriteLine(StopBytes - StartBytes);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public abstract class A
{
    public int TheInt { get; set; }
    public string GetString(double dbl)
    {
        return dbl.ToString();
    }
}

public class B
{
    public int TheInt { get; set; }
    public string GetString(double dbl)
    {
        return dbl.ToString();
    }
}

public class C : A
{
}

public class D : B
{
}
```

Thank you all for your help.
Ps. If it matters, I ran the benchmark in a .NET Core 2.0 Console Application.